# engendered the extinction of

Tags: word-usage

engender - be the source or cause of something (learnersdictionary.com)

- cause a particular situation, atmosphere or feeling to occur (Collin Cobuild Dictionary)

(ex) The issue has engendered a considerable amount of debate. (learnersdictionary)

(ex) That sudden creativity has engendered its own literature. (idoceonline dictionary)

(ex) The changes in society were engendered by the war. (idoceonline)

(ex) Every cloud engenders not a storm. (freedictionary)

I have no problem with the dictionary examples. I have made up the example below using the verb.

(1a) Scientists have been trying to figure out what engendered the extinction of dinosaurs. Recent findings might answer their question.

Am I using the verb correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I think technically it works, but, to me, "engender" connotes active participation by the thing doing the engendering; either the thing does the engendering, or something that the thing did caused the engendering.

I think "caused" or "was the source of" would work better in that particular example.

Comment: I like how you explained the correct usage of the word. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Consider marking the answer as correct? Also, you're example is somewhat close to the freedictionary example that you have there, but even that one sounds off to me. Oddly enough, the four examples that you gave are seemingly ordered according to how "not weird" they sound, from normal at the top to off at the bottom.